# What can I do when my object detection model learns background images instead the objects?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, machine-learning-model, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm training a machine learning model using [YOLOv5 from Ultralytics](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) (arch: YOLOv5s6).
The task is to detect and identify laundry symbols.
For that, I've scraped and labeled 600 images from Google.

Using this dataset, I receive a result with an **mAP around 0.6**.

But **600 images** is a tiny dataset and there are multiple laundry symbols where I have only 1-4 images for training and symbols where I have 100 and more.

So I started writing a Python script which generates more images of laundry symbols.
The script basically takes a background image and adds randomly positioned 1-10 laundry symbols in different colors and rotations. No background is used twice.
With that script, **I generated around 6.000 entirely different images with laundry symbols** that every laundry symbol is at least 800 times in the dataset.

**Here are examples of the generated data:**
[image]
[image]

I combined the scraped and the generated dataset and retrained the model with the same configuration. The result is really bad: the **mAP dropped to 0.15** and the model **overfits**. The confusion matrix told me why:
[image]

### ***Why is the model learning the background instead the objects?***

First I thought my annotation might be wrong, but the training script from Ultralytics saves a few examples of training batch images - there the boxes are drawn perfectly around the generated symbols.

For completeness, below are more analytics added about the training:

### More analytics

Labels
[image]
Curves
[image]
More examples from the dataset
[image]

Comment: Is your model trained to recognize other objects other than laundry symbols? If not, it could be normal that it tries to recognize laundry symbols when they don't exist in an image. Perhaps you could train a few samples of anything very different and ignore those samples objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on Reddit and got a few replies. The main point why my model is not performing on synthetic data, is because **YOLO is looking at the whole picture and tries to learn the context** and not only the patterns of laundry symbols. The background is just too random for YOLO.

A Reddit user even created a video about this, explaining it using a card game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auEvX0nO-kw

**Referenced Reddit posts:**

- https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/ydc9n1/p_object_detection_model_learns_backgrounds_and/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/ydbkaf/object_detection_model_learns_backgrounds_and_not/